# Dynamic image is not loaded via :src

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, webpack

I am working on a simple Vue app, using **vue-cli** and webpack for that purpose.

So basicly i have 2 components, a parent and a child component ~

**like this:**

```
<template>
  <div class="triPeaks__wrapper">
    <div class="triPeaks">
      <tri-tower class="tower"></tri-tower>
      <tri-tower class="tower"></tri-tower>
      <tri-tower class="tower"></tri-tower>
    </div>
    <div class="triPeaks__line">
      <tower-line :towerLine="towerLineCards" />
    </div>
    <tri-pack />
  </div>
</template>
```

the towerLineCards is the important thing there, it is a prop that is passed to the tower-line component, it is basicly a array with 10 elements, it is a array with 10 numbers that are shuffled, so it can be something like that:

**[1,5,2,6,8,9,16,25,40,32]**

this array is create via beforeMount on the lifecycle.

**On the child component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="towerLine-wrapper">
    <div class="towerLine">
      <img v-for="index in 10" :key="index" class="towerLine__image" :src="getImage(index)" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    towerLine: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  method: {
    getImage (index) {
      return '@/assets/images/cards/1.png'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .towerLine {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    left: -40px;

    &__image {
      width: 80px;
      height: 100px;

      &:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 3px;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

the issue is with the :src image that i am returning via the getImage(), this way it is not working. If i change to just src it works just fine, i did this way just to test, because the number in the path should be dynamic when i got this to work.

What is wrong with this approach? any help?

Thanks

Comment: add getImage() inside `computed`

Comment: See difference between method and computed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350862/method-vs-computed-in-vue

Comment: that don't solve the problem, i added a method because I need the index to know the image to render. I changed it to a computed property and return the static string. Same issue. if i pass directly the path the only difference is that with :src it doesn''t work and with src it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use a computed property instead of a method for `getImage()`.

And to solve the other problem, you could add `require(YOUR_IMAGE_PATH)` when you call your specific image or put it inside `/static/your_image.png` instead of `@/assets/images/cards/1.png`.