# Why computed property in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner to vue.js. What is the reason to use computed property instead of methods. Why am asking this question is, because the both computed property and methods do the same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method vs Computed in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350862/method-vs-computed-in-vue)

Comment: You could read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods can get attributes and need to be called manually, computed is not.
Also you no need to clone code while multiple using. Think about computed properties like a shortcut to you additional logic.

Putting too much logic in your templates can make them bloated and hard to maintain. For example:

```
<div id="example">
  {{ message.split('').reverse().join('') }}
</div>
```

The same, using computed property:

```
<div id="example">
  {{ reversedMessage }}
</div>
```

Vue code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

**Difference**

But main difference as i think, is caching. When you call **method** 5 times, you get 5 computings. On the other side a **computed property** is computing only once (when changing), and then return a cached value.