# Vue CLI 3 typescript - Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Vue'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have this weird error that makes no sense. It's saying that `isGenre` does not exist on the type `Vue`, but `ìsGenre`is actually a computed property

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

import { WIDTH_TWO_ICONS } from '@/const/tables-style'

export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        list: Array,
        listType: String
    },
    data: () => ({ WIDTH_TWO_ICONS }),
    computed: {
        isGenre(): boolean {
            return this.listType === 'genre'
        },
        isMood(): boolean {
            return this.listType === 'mood'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        routerLink(paramsId: number): object {
            return { name: 'GenreOrMoodEdit', params: { id: paramsId }, query: { type: this.isGenre ? 'genre' : 'mood' } }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Error

```
59:93 Property 'isGenre' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
    57 |     methods: {
    58 |         routerLink(paramsId: number): object {
  > 59 |             return { name: 'GenreOrMoodEdit', params: { id: paramsId }, query: { type: this.isGenre ? 'genre' : 'mood' } }
       |                                                                                             ^
    60 |         }
    61 |     }
    62 | })
```

**Main.ts**

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    // Global properties can be declared
    // on the `VueConstructor` interface
    interface VueConstructor {
        $axios: any
        router: any
    }
    interface Vue {
        $axios: any
        router: any
    }
}

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import '@/plugins'
import '@/directives'

import '@/sass/main.sass'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Tsconfig.js**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": ["node", "mocha", "chai"],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "files": ["src/interfaces/*"]
}
```

**Tslint.js**

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "warning",
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": ["node_modules/**", "./src/assets/icons/*"]
    },
    "rules": {
        "quotemark": [true, "single", "avoid-escape"],
        "arrow-parens": false,
        "semicolon": false,
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
        "max-line-length": [true, 160],
        "ordered-imports": false,
        "interface-name": false,
        "trailing-comma": false,
        "no-unused-expression": true,
        "object-literal-shorthand": false,
        "curly": false,
        "no-console": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method return type / signature look different than in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350932/3254405 and also first example uses function keyword may be try this way..

Comment: I can remove the return type and the error doesn't go away

Comment: You could define an interface: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8406#issuecomment-419605178

Comment: I find it very unnecessary, I should be able to access computed properties without having to define interfaces for each of them.. In fact I can access computed properties without problems elsewhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining your `list` prop as an `Array`.

`Array` is an alias for `ArrayConstructor` type.

[image: arrayconstructor]

The constructor of `ArrayConstructor` returns `Array<any>`, which is different from `ArrayConstructor`.

**Workaround:**

Create an interface for the `list` property.

ie.

`list` will be an array of `Item`.

```
interface Item { ... }
```

Cast the `Array` to a function that returns the interface.

```
props: {
  list: Array as () => Item[],
}
```

Comment: I fixed it with `itemsList: { type: Array } as PropOptions<IGenre[] | IMood[]>` and it seems to have fixed the problem although I still don't understand it, since the computed was referencing the other props, and not "list" (or not itemsList)

Comment: Sadly, even though the computed property is not using the `list` prop it breaks. Just make sure to cast any prop which type is an `Array`. If I am not mistaken, there is a PR that exposes `Prop` instead of `PropOptions` to fix this issue, but it has not been merged. Hopefully with Vue 3, which will be fully written in TypeScript, these kind of things will get more attention.