# Why does the following Vue.js code not work when switching from computed to methods?

Tags: vue.js

In the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/willywg/2g7m5qy5/

the button is disabled based on the state of the checkbox.

But when I change:

```
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms;
    }
  }
```

to

```
  methods: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms;
    }
  }
```

the enabling / disabling no longer works.

Why is this?

According to the documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

shouldn't both work the same in this example?

Comment: because computed is reactive, methods are not. if using methods in this case you need to call that methods every time you check/un-check the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties look for changes but methods need to be called with something like @change or @click for example. In this case, you can actually just bind your data object without either.

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms' /> I accept terms!!!
    </label>
  </p>
  <button :disabled='!terms'>Send Form</button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    terms: false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Computed and Methods are two different thing**

**method**: call when you wan to do sth, like call an action/mutation or do something other than dealing with store/state

**computed**: you can use returned value to bind sth in template html, some changing value that changes according to some computations. If it wont change then just bind it to a date/state

In your current script computed locating `isDisabled` data change all the time .
so whenever your data is changing its function triggering automatically.

But, if you want this in methods then you should trigger the function manually. 
Example:

```
<input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms' @change="isDisabled" /> I accept terms!!!
```

it will call isDisabled method when it will change.

For more details [`Methods vs Computed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350862/method-vs-computed-in-vue). Thanks