# Vuex mapMutations isn't working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a namespaced store (namespaced: true) and I'm trying to access it via mapMutations. When I call it via mapMutations it results in a 'not a function' error. When I call it directly via this.$store it works fine.  Why does the mapMutations version not work?  Pseduo-code is shown below. FWIW I'm using the latest Vue/Vuex versions.

```
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

computed: {
  ...mapGetters('someModule', ['foo']),
  ...mapMutations('someModule', ['bar']),
}
mounted() {
   this.$store.commit('someModule/bar'); // This works
   this.bar(); // This gives me a "this.bar() is not a function" error
   this.baz();
}
methods: {
  baz() {
   this.bar(); // This gives me a "this.bar() is not a function" error
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutation/Actions are `function` which stay inside `methods`

```
...mapMutations('someModule', ['bar']),
```

Should be inside `methods`

```
methods: {
  ...mapMutations('someModule', ['bar']),
  executeBar() {
     this.bar()
   }
}
```

For more info and comparison between `methods` and `computed` see this [Method vs Computed in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350862/method-vs-computed-in-vue)

Comment: I tried putting it in the method and I get the same error.  Code is updated above

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 It's your call to `mapMutations` that needs to move into the `methods`. So `methods: { ...mapMutations('someModule', ['bar']) }`.

Comment: Yep @skirtle, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: ahh Thanks @skirtle I missed to add the line inside methods.